# Hadoop Dfs start error: NoSuchMethodError : addDeprecations

Tags: hadoop

I had hadoop set up in pseudo distributed mode, and it was running perfectly fine. But after locking the screen on mac, while it was running and after loggin back in, I couldnt open the dashboard or any other thing. 
The jps command showed only jps running. I tried stopping and restarting again, but i get the following error, and the namenodes and datanodes do not start.

```
   ./start-dfs.sh 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.addDeprecations([Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration$DeprecationDelta;)V
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.HdfsConfiguration.addDeprecatedKeys(HdfsConfiguration.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.HdfsConfiguration.<clinit>(HdfsConfiguration.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf.<clinit>(GetConf.java:126)
    Starting namenodes on []
    Password:
```

I didnt change any properties in the hadoop conf files.
Thanks in advance for any help.

When trying to run the basic example from hadoop installation guide, I get the following error:

```
$ bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.9.0.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Comment: Hadoop version and Java version, pls ?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that earlier. Hadoop version 2.9.0, java 1.8

Comment: how do you get Hadoop-bin installation files?Is it complete? Is there any jar file in `HADOOP_HOME/share` directory?

Comment: There are jar files in HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs. I downloaded the stable version from the official hadoop site.

Comment: Did you set environment variables like `HADOOP_HOME` or `HADOOP_PREFIX` and  `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home .  I havent set the HADOOP_HOME or HADOOP_PREFIX. Left them as it is in hadoop-env.sh

Comment: Check, is it the correct path? I think It is strange path!

Comment: That is the path in a Mac. And it was working prior to today

Comment: Run Command `java -version` and post it's output

Comment: java -version output : java version "1.8.0_162"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: from which tutorial did you install the Hadoop?

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

Comment: start dfs command is asking for a password, which means you didn't setup passwordless SSH or something in that script requires elevated permissions. If you get no such method, or no class definition, then your classpath got misconfigured... Hint: Don't sleep or shut off your computer while HDFS is running - it'll corrupt itself. I learned the hard way